# Prove equivalence relationship

Tags: relations

How would I go about doing this?
I assume proving it's reflexive, symmetrical and transitive
Show that the relation $R = \{(x, y):3x − 5y \text{ is even }\}$ is an equivalence relationship.

Comment: Are there any confines on $x$ and $y$? For example, what if $x=0.1$ and $y=0.2$. Is $1.3$ even? If you want $x$ and $y$ to be integers then I recommend you used $m$ and $n$ instead of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: There are no confines. Why would I use $m$ and $n$?

Comment: There are confines: you're assuming that $x$ and $y$ are integers. It's common to use $m$ and $n$ for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $R \subset {\mathbb Z}^2$.

$3x-5y$ is even iff $3x$ and $5y$ are both even or both odd.

Terms are even iff respective variables are even, so the given relation is equivalent to 'both variables are even or both are odd'.

The three basic properties are obvious now.